# How to inspect the elements in flutter web application. how to do automation testing in flutter web application

Tags: browser-automation

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SN4rr.png)

I'm trying to inspect the elements but it not responding. can any suggest how to do automation testing in flutter web application.
or
suggest any other testing tool support the flutter web application testing.

Thanks
Anudeep

Answer (score 1):

I did not find any framework which supports flutter web automation but there is a workaround that we can enable accessibility by doing force click using JavaScript.
Run this script in browser console:

```
document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane').shadowRoot.querySelector('flt-semantics-placeholder').click({force: true});
```

Now you can identify all the elements using aria-label:

```
document.querySelector('flt-glass-pane').shadowRoot.querySelectorAll('[aria-label]')
```